# Debugging php session timeout

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, pear

I got one unsolvable bug at work.
I got a logout timer at the bottom of the page set at 45 mins

Every time a page request is made the session timeout gets updated and everything seems fine and it works.

Thing is, the client is using some pages longer than 45 mins(Editing in wysiwyg) and needs to reset the session timout without reloading the page.

My solution to this is to send an ajax request updating the session.
Everything seems fine.
Dumping the session variable shows correct values.
But the session timeout wont extend.
At some point the session times out anyway.

Is it impossible to reset the session timeout through ajax?
Anyway to debug this problem would be nice?

This webapplication is using liveuser from PEAR and the code is messy as hell!
I cant figure out what is happening!

Comment: The only way is pinging session before every 44 minutes

Comment: resetting a session timeout with ajax works fine, we're doing it on our webapp. I think there's a problem with your code, but without the relevant part, It'll be difficult to help

Comment: Thing is its so big i cant really point it out.
I guess i need a better way to debug.
But good to know that it acctually is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not impossible to set the session timeout through ajax.

Comment: `No, it is not impossible`
or
`No, it is not possible`